# How to specify a subdirectory for an object file with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Everything I've seen about this is very specific to makefiles, so I'm going to ask this more generally.

I want to compile an object file, in a way that I can place the newly compiled object file, in a subdirectory of the one my c file is currently in.

I am looking for something along the lines of

```
gcc -g -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -c src/list.c  obj/list.o
```

So I pull something out src/ make an object file out of it, and put it into the obj/ directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-o` option to specify the path of the output file.

E.g.  `gcc -o some/where/else/foo.o src/foo.c`

Comment: We all start somewhere :-)  Be sure to consult the `man` pages for questions about usage like this!